# Missing up/down scrollbar arrow buttons in Chrome 32 update

Tags: google-chrome, browser, scroll, scrollbar, google-chrome-devtools

I believe it was a result of Chrome update 32 but my browsers scroll bars have changed.  Now I have a new modern looking scroll bar which looks nice but no longer has up down arrow buttons.

The problems is I found these to be quite useful for precision line by line page navigation, especially in my app's interface and now I seem to have lost that functionality.

Are they gone forever, is this the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is a known issue: ChromeOS style for scrollbars is being applied on Windows.
Check out [this discussion](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/oALMlQeYnG4%5B1-25-true%5D), which also links to the related Chromium issues and to Chrome extensions to fix the scrollbar style.

Comment: So looks like they will be making a re-appearance, thanks for the link ochedru!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any way to get em back but it seems like they're entirely gone (forever). But if you're a Webdeveloper you might be interested in custom scrollbar-styling using CSS3.

Lots of stuff about that can be found within a few seconds googling ;)